kubectl on OKE cluster is reporting that the node is low on ephemeral storage when the capacity of a PVC is exceeded
I have a pod that has a persistentVolumeClaim volume with a 10Gi capacity.
      volumes:
      - name: my-persistent-volume-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-persistent-volume-claim-output-01

After deployment, kubectl get pvc -o wide shows:
NAME                                         STATUS   VOLUME                                 CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   VOLUMEATTRIBUTESCLASS   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
my-persistent-volume-claim-output-01         Bound    my-persistent-volume-claim-db1         10Gi       RWO            manual         <unset>                 18h   Filesystem

When that capacity is exceeded, the pod is torn down, but running kubectl describe pod <podname> indicates that the node is running low on ephemeral storage.
Warning  Evicted              41s   kubelet            The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Threshold quantity: 5710482044, available: 5024400Ki. Container test-container was using 11812Ki, request is 0, has larger consumption of ephemeral-storage.
Normal   Killing              41s   kubelet            Stopping container test-container

The pod remains in an ERROR state, but a new pod is created without any issue - it will remain operational until the data written to the PVC volume exceeds the capacity, at which point this cycle repeats. The data from every pod is written to the same directory on the host and persists after the pods are evicted.
I have created an emptyDir volume type to compare the error returned - it does not reference ephemeral storage, and explicitly specifies the reason for the teardown being a volume exceeding it's limit, rather than the node being low on ephemeral-storage
  Warning  Evicted              44s   kubelet  Usage of EmptyDir volume "tmp-vol" exceeds the limit "1G".
  Normal   Killing              44s   kubelet  Stopping container test-container

The node has no memory pressure in either case
In short, why would exceeding the capacity of a persistentVolumeClaim result in a node being low on ephemeral storage? Why is ephemeral storage on the node of any relevance to a PVC volume type? My understanding of volume types is that ephemeral storage is used by emptyDir, configMap, downwardAPI, and secret volume types, which this volume is NOT. Is this just a confusing error message or is there some other error occurring that I am unaware of?

The get pvc output suggests a manual storage class; how are you configuring the PersistentVolumeClaim?  If you have a hostPath or local volume, or if your cluster's storage provisioner does something similar, then a PersistentVolume can still use node storage.

(ephemeral-storage as a resource class generally refers to non-volume container filesystem use.)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
